# Is it wise for researchers to thank Alexandra Elbakyan (founder of Sci-Hub) in the paper acknowledgements?

Tags: open-access, acknowledgement, science, sci-hub

[Alexandra Elbakyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Elbakyan) founded the site [Sci-Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub), which allows bypassing publisher paywalls.

If this service is used by researchers to access papers that would otherwise be out of their reach - due to their university not having subscribed to publishers or not being able to buy papers due to budget constraints - is it a good idea / wise to thank Alexandra in the Acknowledgement section of a paper citing the otherwise unattainable papers?

For example, "We would like to thank Alexandra Elbakyan for her work / contributions to science" without explicitly mentioning any specifics.

A similar question was already asked with the top rated answer pointing out that it would be unwise for paper authors to [admit to illegal activity in a formal document](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/41949/97258).
This seems like a reasonable point.

Reseachers thanking someone for their contribution to science does not seem illegal and might get some readers of a paper to research the background of the acknowledgement.

Comment: Did you read the answers of the question you linked to? The answers cover all that you ask...

Comment: I am not sure whether it is 'wise', but it is definitely a very good idea. I should do that as well. (Maybe an attentive editor will ask you to be more specific about her contribution or to remove that acknowledgement, but give it a try.) As Solar Mike said, with this formulation you do not admit any illegal activity.

Comment: I honestly don't see the difference between this question and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41946/can-i-thank-websites-that-host-illegal-book-downloads-in-the-acknowledgements-se/41949#41949 Voting to close.

Comment: @PuzzledBiologist I said no such thing, also, the first answer points out one has to live with the consequences ie raising the flag of a bad idea... I would NOT make such an acknowledgement for the reasons outlined in the answers to the other question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I was wondering about using the acknowledgements in a subversive way, i.e. not admitting to an illegal activity specifically, which I agree would be a bad idea. I think @Buffy's answer makes a good point. I also agree that my question was very similar to the related one (hence why I linked it).

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened, because it asks about a specific case which can be handled in a specific way. Nowadays it's pretty common to [include her in acknowledgements](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="thank+alexandra+elbakyan"). You can just say "for her support" or something similar which doesn't imply anything problematic.

Comment: Not a dupe, because the other question's title is "websites which host illegal book downloads" - and it is certainly not established that Sci-Hub is that, universally.

Comment: An lawyer assured me that downloading from SciHub is legal, only uploading is not. Obviously, one can't distribute the downloaded material, but individual use for academic purposes is within the fair use provision of US copyright law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping here that you want to express your opinion that we need a site on which broad copyright license is granted by authors, rather than held closely. I hope you aren't expressing favor of a site in which copyrights of others are simply ignored and not respected and on which illegal activities occur.

I, too, think a site on which people voluntarily agree to a broad license to their work is granted would be a very valued thing. But I wouldn't praise any site that actively encourages the disrespect of authors and their rights.

I don't have a lot of use, either, for journals and other publishers that demand the rights from authors, but that is a different problem.

But, to answer the question directly, associating yourself professionally with behavior treated by many as unethical and even illegal, is probably a mistake. Tactical, if nothing else. You won't really effect the needed change that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think your the viewpoint of seeing it as a tactical professional mistake is valuable.

Comment: "You won't really effect the needed change that way": I don't think that's obvious. Publicly acknowledging your use of Sci-Hub helps making it acceptable (by protecting the other people who do it), which casts a spotlight on the problem of access to scientific literature. The more people who do it in their paper, the stronger the effect.

Comment: @a3nm, hmmm, does robbing corner bodegas make it more acceptable or protect other people who do it? How about other things that may not be explicitly criminal, but are frowned upon by most people. Publicly berating your children, for example.

Comment: @Buffy I'd be interested in a source for the implicit claim that using Sci-Hub is "frowned upon by most people". My own experience is that people are usually fine with it, and agree that it shows a problem with the system; they're just not comfortable saying publicly that they use it because it's illegal, not immoral. (And about the content of your answer: I have yet to meet a scientist who doesn't want their work to be read as widely as possible, given they don't benefit from subscription money. Making this about the rights of authors, rather than of publishers, is nitpicking at best, IMO.)

Comment: Are authors and copyright holders the same?